# generate log files for an angular-electron application

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, winston

I need to write log files besides the console for my angular electron application, I tried to use Winston library for that but it didn't work for me, how can I do it ?

This is the LogSnapsService that supposed to write on the logfile

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import * as winston from 'winston';

const logger = winston.createLogger({
  transports: [
    new winston.transports.File({
      filename: 'logs/apptest.log',
      level: 'info',
      format: winston.format.combine(
        winston.format.timestamp(),
        winston.format.json()
      ),
    }),
  ],
});

@Injectable({
  providedIn:'root'
})

export class LogSnapsService{


  logViewPost(postId: number) {
    logger.info(`User viewed post ${postId}`);
  }

  logCreatePost() {
    logger.info('User created a new post');
  }
}
```

this is the newFaceSnapComponent.ts, is responsible to create a new item, i inject the LogSnapsService to use it in the OnSubmitForm() function.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { map, Observable, tap } from 'rxjs';
import { FaceSnap } from 'src/app/core/models/face-snap.model';
import {FaceSnapsService} from "../../services/face-snaps.service";
import { LogSnapsService } from '../../log-snaps-service';




@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-face-snap',
  templateUrl: './new-face-snap.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-face-snap.component.scss']
})
export class NewFaceSnapComponent implements OnInit {

  snapForm !: FormGroup;
  faceSnapPreview$! : Observable<FaceSnap>;
  urlRegex !: RegExp;

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private faceSnapService: FaceSnapsService,
              private router: Router, private logsnapsservice: LogSnapsService){}

  /*** some code ***/
    );
  }

  onSubmitForm() {
    this.faceSnapService.addFaceSnap(this.snapForm.value).pipe(
        tap(() => this.router.navigateByUrl('/facesnaps'))
    ).subscribe();
    this.logsnapsservice.logCreatePost();
}

}
```